# Elevate rights in current directory with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

For example I'm in `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tools` and I'm trying to stay here as admin.

I tried this way, gluing together different commands:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit" & -windowstyle hidden -Command Start-Process powershell  -ArgumentList '-NoExit', '-Command cd %V' -Verb runAs""
```

The PATH changes to `C:\WINDOWS\system32` why? How to elevate rights in current directory via simple command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$PWD` from the calling process to change the location on startup:

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoExit', "-Command cd '$pwd'; & .\actual\script\you\want\to\run.ps1" -Verb runAs
```

Comment: work fine ```Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-NoExit', "-Command cd '$pwd'" -Verb runAs```